# Some Unnatural Instances of Present Subjunctive Uses

Tags: grammar, subjunctives, subordinate-clauses, present-subjunctive

As far as I know, the present subjunctive is used in subordinate clauses that follow verbs expressing a desire, a demand, a recommendation, or a resolve.

However, I came across the following examples which seems not to be included in any of the mentioned categories:

> He must be tended with the same care, whether he **be** friend or foe.
>
> Whoever he **be**, he shall not go unpunished.
>
> I am running faster lest she **catch** me.

I wonder why the simple present forms of the verbs are not used instead in such example sentences.

Comment: "As we know" is always a dangerous way to start a question.  More often than not you don't know it.  Make sure you always cite a grammar source for any "As we know" facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern English the present indicative may be used in all those examples.  You quotes are from the English of 100+ years ago (or people emulating such dated English) in which the subjunctive was used much more often. It was used in many situations in which the Latin subjunctive would have been used.

So in this old-fashioned English, and in formal styles that emulate old fashioned English, it is correct to use the subjunctive in these non-indicative clauses.

Comment: According to Lexico, your first statement (that the present indicative may be used in all those examples) is dubious: "There are very few contexts in English where the subjunctive mood is, strictly speaking, required: *lest* remains one of them."  ("Lest" is of course a formal and literary word.)

Comment: In modern English the sentence with "lest" would be rephrased completely.  "I'm running faster, or she might catch me".  (modals not subjunctive).  "I'm running faster for fear that she might catch me"